# Rolle's theorem question?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $q(x) = x^n + ax + b$ where $a,b$ are elements of $\mathbb R$.  Prove that $q$ has at the most:

i) two distinct real roots of $n$ is even
ii)  three distinct real roots if $n $is odd.

Other than knowing this has to do with Rolle's theorem, I'm completely stuck.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: you should be convinced that this could be true by taking $n=2$ and $n=3$? have you done that.. ?

Comment: I know it's true, but I don't know how to prove it...?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  How many real roots can $q^\prime(x)$ have?  If there are more than the given number of distinct roots for $q(x)$, what does Rolle's theorem say about the number of roots of the derivative (by considering consecutive pairs of roots of $q(x)$)?

Comment: I could not get this entirely... suppose $q(x)$ is an even polynomial then $q'(x)$ will be an odd polynomial so it should have at least one real root So? I am sorry.. could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik $q^\prime(x)$ has a special form: $nx^{n-1}+a$, which means that it can only have $1$ real root $x =(-\frac{a}{n})^{1/(n-1)}$ if $n$ is even and up to $2$ real roots $x = \pm (-\frac{a}{n})^{1/(n-1)}$ (none if $a>0$) if $n$ is odd.